# Calculate PDF page height and width

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation

I've checked around SO and see potential solutions to this question, plus I already have a potential solution which I'll explain in the question, but I'm going to try and reach from another angle.  I'm using [PDF4NET](http://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/overview.htm) to convert Computer output to laser disc (COLD) documents to PDF.  These COLD documents are just plain text, but do not appear to be on standard page sizes (ie. letter, tabloid, legal, etc...) and I'm not able to pull any page size information from the document itself.  This causes an issue, when I tried to convert them to a portrait (8.5 x 11) page, where a single line may end up wrapping over to the next line.  I want to be able to avoid this.

Here are the knowns that I use when I try to convert the document:

1. COLD document - I know the length of the longest line of characters and I know the number of lines that are on the page.
2. Font - The resulting PDF document will be Courier size 10
3. Margins - Margins can vary for each document but we have that available
4. DPI - This will always be 72 (PDF's default DPI)

With these knowns I determine the length longest line of characters with:

```
Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(longestLine, new Font("Courier", 10, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point));
```

I use `textSize.Width` to set the PDF page height & width, essentially creating a square page.  This "appears" to keep the text from wrapping, but there is a lot of white space on the right side and bottom of the page.

### Question:

Is there a better way to calculate the height and width of the PDF page, with the given knowns, so the text can fit without having so much white space?  If there is more information needed that would help in the better calculation, what other information would be needed?  The goal is to create a document of such size where no lines wrap and the margins look the same all around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out [PDF4NET](http://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/overview.htm) has its own `MeasureString()` in the `PDFFont` class which was more accurate.

With known marginal spacing, font size, longest line length, and number of lines we were able to calculate the height and width of a page with:

```
PDFFont font = new PDFFont(PDFFontFace.Courier, 10);
double leftMargin = (double)LeftMargin.Value * 72;
double topMargin = (double).TopMargin.Value * 72;
double width = font.MeasureString(longestLine) + (leftMargin * 2);
double height = (LinesOfText.Count * font.Size) + (topMargin * 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the width in pixels provided by TextRenderer assumes a definition of 96 dpi.

```
int pagewidth = textsize * 72 / 96 + 2*Margin ;
```

Look if Graphics (GDI+) returns different width than TextRenderer (GDI).

```
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1));
SizeF size = graphics.MeasureString(text,myfont) ;
```

Comment: That is already accounted for. As mentioned in the question we always use 72dpi for this conversion

Comment: Try Graphics.MeasureString(). I have updated my answer with some code.

Comment: Graphics.MeasureString() resulted in a larger number which resulted in more white space.

Comment: Does the problem still occurs with better DPI resolution (e.g.300) ? I have some doubt on "Courier" font adjustement for a low resolution (72 dpi).

Comment: Higher resolutions do not resolve the issue either.  I have come up with a solution that appears to be working, but +1 to you for reminding me about applying margins.